# RegEx or Interpreter to interpret an integer/double range input

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, interpreter

I need to verify if a string is in the following format
{x:y} or {x,y,...,z}  where x,y,z are either integers or doubles. 
I was thinking I either need a reg-ex and/or an interpreter.
Does anyone know how to go about this?
Also suggestion to a library that does this would be deeply appreciated.

The second step would be having an interpreter that cand interpret expressions like this:
0.5*{0.4,0.6,0.7} -> {0.2,0.3,0.35}. I realize that the optimal approach would be to define a grammer for this that the interpreter can use.

Thanks,
B

Comment: what kind of double notations are we talking about? only 1.2 or somthing like 1.2E-10

Comment: yes, only 1.2 kind would be just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are a 101 different double formats and Double.TryParse() is built into the .net framework.

I would use a regex or just string.split to get an array of strings that contains your “x,y,z” values then call Double.TryParse on each of the values.

As you have two possible formats, I would first check to see if the input string contains “:” then have separate code to split each format so as to make the code more understandable.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks! I want to make use of the .net built-in functions as much as possible. I am just wondering if there exists open-source a library which does this already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at Regex myself but I do use this for my source of getting them: http://www.regexlib.com/ It also includes a Cheat Sheet and a Regex Tester on that site so you can create them yourself pretty easy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First option

```
\{[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?:[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\}
```

Second

```
\{[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+\}
```

Usage

```
var text = "{1.4,65,2.56}";
Regex regex = new Regex("\{[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+\}");
if(regex.IsMatch(text))
{
    //string matches your criteria
}
```

If you want check both types at once change regex to:

```
\{([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?:[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+)\}
```